# Unable to re-install 16.04 after a failed update two weeks ago

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, system-installation

I am new to Ubuntu, but have used it (minimally) for the last 2 years. After a failed update, my 16.04 refused to work.  When I loaded the live DVD/CD disk, it asked if I wanted to install alongside the 16.04 on the disk.

- I chose to erase and do a "fresh" install. That attempt failed when it couldn't format the hard disk.  I got a errno#5 message, stating a bad DVD drive or hard drive.
- Replaced drives, as well as cables.  Got same error message.
- Burnt new disks at slower speeds from Ubuntu website.  Still same problem.
- Used mini-tool partition program and partitioned hard disk to ext4.  Tried installing, failed again!
- As a last ditch, I bought a new motherboard.  Sad to say..., same results.

Next, I Am going to have my memory tested, but if that checks out good, I don't know what to do next!

Comment: Bad HDD controller maybe? You said you got a new MB though. Hmmm

Comment: All your attempts have been from DVD, have you tried from live USB?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the update "killed" somehow your computer. Send me the results from the Memory Test. Also check your hard disk on another computer to see if it works (the original & the new one). Also send me those results. :)

Regards,

Bajiru